# Agregar un array de objeto a ChartJS

Tags: php, javascript, json, symfony3, twig

Como agregar un array de objetos a chartjs. El controlador de esa vista envía a la plantilla twig un array de objeto.De la forma en que lo estoy haciendono se muestran los valores de mes e imp.En el atributo labels quiero poner el arreglo de meses y en el atributo data el arreglo de imp .Por favor tienen alguna idea de esto? 
Controlador:

```
     /**
 * @Route("/cg1", name="cg1")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function cg1Action(Request $request)
{
    $conn=$this->get('database_connection');
    $consulta="SELECT SUM(consumo_combustible.importe) as imp, MONTH(consumo_combustible.fecha) as mes FROM consumo_combustible WHERE YEAR(consumo_combustible.fecha)=2018 GROUP BY consumo_combustible.fecha";
    $sql=$conn->fetchAll($consulta);
    $jsonResponse = json_encode($sql);

    echo($jsonResponse);
    return $this->render('default/consultag1.html.twig',array(
        'respuesta' => $jsonResponse

    ));
}
```

Plantilla Twig, código js

```
         var  valormes=[];
         var valorimp=[];                      

         $.ajax({
             url: 'http://localhost/PECNEA/web/app_dev.php/cg1', //Tu archivo donde estará tu consulta
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
         })
             .done(function(respuesta) {
                 for (var i = 0; i < respuesta.results.length - 1; i++) {
                     var items = console.log(respuesta.results[i]);

                     valormes.push(items.mes)
                     valorimp.push(items.imp)

                 }


             })
             .fail(function() {
                 console.log("Error al cargar el arreglo");
             });

var areaChartData = {

  labels  :  valormes,
  datasets: [
    {
      label               : '2018',
      fillColor           : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      strokeColor         : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      pointColor          : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
      pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
      pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      data                : valorimp
    }

  ]
}
```

Comment: ¿Cúal es el formato de tu objeto cg? ¿Que dice el mensaje de error?

Comment: Cg es un arreglo de arreglo. Mire la consulta sql que está dentro de la función de la clase controladora es el primer código que colgué.

Comment: Con {{cg.mes}} obtengo un arreglo al igual que con {{cg.imp}} en el error me menciona que los dos son array y por supuesto tienen igual dimensión

Comment: [{"imp":"600","mes":"1"},{"imp":"400","mes":"2"},{"imp":"2200","mes":"3"}]

Comment: Ese formato, tu Array[objetc] no es el adecuado para char.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan sencillo como esto, la variable resultado dentro del código js la obtengo con 
*var arr= JSON.parse('{{ resultado|raw }}');*
Demostración del código js:

```
  var valormes=[];
  var valorimp=[];  
  // Estructura que tiene el arreglo a través de la variable resultado que envía el controlador a la vista twig 
  //arr= [{"imp":"3000","mes":"2"},{"imp":"830","mes":"3"},{"imp":"1900","mes":"4"}];

  var arr= JSON.parse('{{ resultado|raw }}');

  for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
       valormes[i]=arr[i].mes;
       valorimp[i]=arr[i].imp;
  }

   console.log(valormes);

   console.log(valorimp);



var areaChartData = {

  labels  :  valormes,
  datasets: [
    {
      label               : '2018',
      fillColor           : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      strokeColor         : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      pointColor          : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
      pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
      pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      data                : valorimp
    }

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para los labels y data de [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) solo le valen los array[value]. Debes de [extraer esa información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) para cargarla en la configuración del chart.

```
let arrmes = cg.map(mes => cg.mes);
let arrimp = cg.map(mes => cg.imp);

var areaChartData = {

  labels  : {{arrmes}}
  datasets: [
    {
      label               : '2018',
      fillColor           : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      strokeColor         : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      pointColor          : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
      pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
      pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
      pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      data                : {{arrimp}}
    }

  ]
}
```

Comment: Tuve que realizar algunos cambios utilizando json para poder obtener el array dentro del código js

Comment: Edité nuevamente la publicación si tienes alguna idea sobre esto, le agradecería que me ayudara.

Comment: @BarbaraRossVeitia si vos cambias tu pregunta a cada rato, las respuestas dejan de ser validas. Por favor, has una pregunta, y cuando este contestada pasa a otra pregunta distinta, si no hay que estar modificando a cada rato la respuesta y esa no es la finalidad.

Comment: tienes toda la razón